# Unable to setup Cocoapods, pod setup --verbose command failed

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapods on my mac to use for iOS apps. So before finding a cocoapod tutorial, I may have tried to install a cocoapod for an xcode project with `pod init` and some other random things. I don't think `pod init` worked but another similar command did something

I then decided it would be a better idea to follow a tutorial from the beginning, so I started with installing cocoapods with the `sudo gem install cocoapods`, which worked.

However, when I typed `pod setup --verbose`, terminal threw an error which also happened when I typed `pod setup`

```
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun\n") (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Please help, I can't find any answers on stackoverflow or any other website.

Comment: Check if you have installed command line tools. Go to Xcode -> Preferenced -> Locations and select Command Line Tools. Check if it is showing current Xcode.

Comment: @adev Woahhh thanks so much dude!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Based on the error message you are getting, it seems like you don't have command line tools installed. You need to install that and then go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools and confirm you have current Xcode version selected there.

[image: Xcode Command line tools]

Comment: After updating macOS Mojave to macOS Catalina, i run '$ chsh -s /bin/zsh' command in Terminal. And then i select Xcode 10.2 (Or the Xcode version in which you are working on). Thanks @adev!!

Comment: @AnjaliKevadiya, Glad to know it helped.